# Integration Question: Completing the Square/Trig Sub yields a different answer than integral table.

Tags: calculus, integration

After the completing the square,

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + 2x - 3}$$

becomes,

$$ \int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2 - 4}$$

The integral table in my book says the antiderivative is,

$$\frac{1}{2a} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{x-a}{x+a} \Biggr\rvert + \, C$$

or,

$$ \frac{1}{4} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{x-1}{x+3} \Biggr\rvert + \, C$$

Using trig sub, and $\displaystyle u=a\sec\theta$ I obtained,

$$\frac{1}{2}\int csc \, \theta \, d\theta$$

which corresponds to

$$-\frac{1}{2} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}} \Biggr\rvert + \, C $$

I am having a lot of trouble putting this result in the form presented in the table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you write the steps in your trigonometric substitution?

Comment: And, just to be clear, you set $u=x+1$ also, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-\frac{1}{2} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}} \Biggr\rvert + \, C $$

You can take the square of the term in the absolut value signs. At the same time you take the square root. Remember the rule $log|x^a|=a\cdot log|x|$

$$-\frac{1}{2} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \left( \frac{(x+3)^2}{x^2+2x-3 } \right) ^{1/2}\Biggr\rvert + \, C=-\frac{1}{4} ln \, \Biggl\lvert  \frac{(x+3)^2}{x^2+2x-3 } \Biggr\rvert + \, C $$

Linear factors of the denominator

$$=-\frac{1}{4} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{(x+3)^2}{(x+3)\cdot(x-1)   } \Biggr\rvert + \, C$$

Cancelling $(x+3)$. And taking away the negative sign. To neutralize this change you have to exchange the numerator and denominator.

$$=\frac{1}{4} ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{x-1}{x+3   }  \Biggr\rvert + \, C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$-\frac{1}{2} \ln \, \Biggl\lvert \frac{x+3}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}} \Biggr\rvert = -\frac12 \ln \left| \sqrt{\frac{(x+3)^2}{(x-1)(x+3)}} \right| = -\frac14 \ln \left| \frac{x+3}{x-1} \right| = \frac14 \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+3}\right|$$